# JQM: multiple select option selection on change event

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, binding

I have a (multiple) select in my JQM page.

I need to force option with value 'A' de-selection on any other option selection.

HTML is like this:

```
<select name="select-1" id="select-1" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" />
   <option value='A'>a</option>
   <option value='B'>b</option>
   <option value='C'>c</option>
</select>
```

I'm using some code like this, with no success... :-(

```
$("select#select-1").change(function() {
    $("select#select-1").val('A').attr("selected", false).trigger("refresh");
});
```

It looks like the option I'm trying to de-select is selected, and all others are de-selected (excluded the current one) ... :-(

A jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/marcolino/P6XwK/).

Comment: do I understand that correctly: if option with value='B' is selected, you like to deselect option with value='A'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around a little bit with your problem and assuming I did not misunderstand your problem (see comments), this snippets works (however probably there are simpler solutions...)

**If option with value='B' is selected, then option with value='A' will be deselected.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>if B selected, deselect A</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- if B selected, deselect A -->
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
      <select name="select-1" id="select-1" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" />
        <option id="option-A" value='A'>a</option>
        <option id="option-B" value='B'>b</option>
        <option id="option-C" value='C'>c</option>
      </select>
    </div><!-- /content -->
  </div><!-- /page -->

  <script>
    $("#select-1").change(function() {
      var mySelection = $(this).val();
      if (mySelection !== null) {
        if (mySelection.indexOf('B') >= 0) {
          $("#option-A").attr("selected", false);
          $('#select-1').selectmenu('refresh');
        };
      };
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** updated now with `$('#select-1').selectmenu('refresh');` and it now also works in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLVZt/)

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work... :-( I did just create a jsfiddle to test it, and it doesn't work at all (neither on FF nor Chrome). Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/marcolino/P6XwK/. I did also change a bit the question, to better reflect my use case, but the juice is the same...

Comment: Yes, in the browser it works!!! I did try to load jqm 1.2.0 (and not 1.1.1 i was loading on the jsfiddle and on my page), but still no joy. On the jsfiddle it looks like the deselection is shown only after the next change event... :-(

Comment: I did some more tests: moving the script section to the head, your code behaves like mine... Enclosing it in a  "$(document).ready(function() {})" or in a  "$(document).ready(function() {})" doesn't help... We're missing something about event calling or registering logic, I suppose...

Comment: Sorry, in the second "or" I meant "$(document).bind("pageinit", function() {})...

Comment: got it now... finally..., see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLVZt/) using `$('select').selectmenu('refresh');` see also [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/selects/methods.html)

Comment: Perfect! I was missing .selectmenu('refresh') ... Thank you so much!